# import everything from a module except a few methods

Tags: python, import

Is it possible to `import` everything (`*`) from an existing Python module *except* a number of explicitly specified methods?

(Background: Against recommended Python practice it is common in [FEniCS](http://fenicsproject.org/) to do `from dolfin import *`. A few of the methods names contain the string "Test" though (e.g., `TestFunction()`) and are mistaken for unit tests by [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In case you don't have an access to the module, you can also simply remove these methods or variables from a global namespace. Here's how this could be done:

```
to_exclude = ['foo']

from somemodule import *

for name in to_exclude:
    del globals()[name]
```

Comment: Your solution does not work for flask because flask defines a namespace called globals by coincidence.

Comment: If there is just a single name to exclude you don't have to use `globals()` and can simply write `del foo`.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can [define the `__all__`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) module

Add

```
__all__ = ["echo", "surround", "reverse"] #Or whatever your module names are
```

to the file which has these modules, or `__init__.py` of the package you want to import from.

Now

```
from module import *
```

imports *only* the specified modules in `__all__`

Comment: This appears to work if you do it from outside, e.g. `import somemodule; somemodule.__all__ = ['get', 'these', 'guys']; from somemodule import *`

Answer (score 2):

@alexander-zhukov's solution will work most of the time, but not when the imported module coincidentally contains a variable called `globals`.

For example,

```
to_exclude = ['abort']
from flask import *
for name in to_exclude:
    del globals()[name]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The error is because the `flask` package contains a namespace called `globals` (that cannot be called) which will overwrite your current global symbol `globals`.

The following solution will work for flask and others:

```
to_exclude = ['abort']
from flask import *
for name in to_exclude:
    __builtins__.globals().pop(name)
```

However ridiculously, it does not work if you open a Python console and type in the commands manually. I think this is a defect of Python 3. If you want this to work in a Python console, then you have to explicitly import the `builtins` module:

```
import builtins
to_exclude = ['abort']
from flask import *
for name in to_exclude:
    builtins.globals().pop(name)
```