# Import everything except one method or import this method with different name

Tags: python, python-import, python.net

I want to use both C# classes and Python classes in my project. The problem is that some classes have the same name in both Python and C#. Let's say that my class is `myClass`. I'd like to be able to call the following:

```
from namespace import *, myClass as myClassCSharp
```

or

```
from namespace import * except myClass
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import everything from a module except a few methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957657/import-everything-from-a-module-except-a-few-methods)

Comment: It might be better to use `import namespace`, then use names like `namespace.myClass` so that you have some slight idea of where the names are coming from.